psql select md5 hashing by "where in" cluase
I have md5 column called url, i need to achieve this query WHERE url IN ('v1.com', 'v2.com'); in md5 form like this WHERE md5(url) IN md5('v1.com', 'v2.com');
Every thing  well except this part IN md5('v1.com', 'v2.com')
I know there is an way like this IN (md5('v1.com'), md5('v2.com')) and works well but i need to put md5 once not on every value.
I'm trying to do a select query in md5 form, but there is a condition WHERE column IN ('v1.com', 'v2.com');
Full example

For example there are stored urls like those
v1.com v2.com v3.com v4.com

When enquiry with:

SELECT * FROM props WHERE url IN ('v1.com', 'v2.com', 'notexist.com');'

expected output will be



id
url
status_code




1
v1.com
200


2
v2.com
200



How to achieve that but in md5 form to url column ?

Is the url composed of multiple values, in this case, 'v1' and 'v2'?

Could you add some simple data and the expected output ?

@SelVazi    Can you see that clear now?

You could use a subquery, e.g. IN(SELECT md5(url) FROM props WHERE url IN(...)) or a CTE. What exactly is your use case?

@filpa i know this work but, not preferred a subquery for performance.                                                In deep details the url is md5 index i need to search by the index

"I know there is an way like this IN (md5('v1.com'), md5('v2.com')) and works well but i need to put md5 once not on every value." Can you explain the reason for this requirement? Since you're checking against a hash, the each element of the IN also has to be hashed, so there's not much you can do to get around this. You could define a Postgres function that takes an array of strings and returns an array of hashes of those strings (and then do WHERE IN (md5_array(url1, url2, ...)), but that's a lot less maintainable.

@filpa Yes your thinking is 100% correct.                                                                                             I'm not found any built in postgres function to handle strings to md5 hashes, in the end of the way i'll create custom function like your explain. thanks

If I'm understanding right...
select *
from props
where url in (
    select md5(*)
    from unnest(array['v1.com', 'v2.com'])
)

Edit:
select *
from props
join (
    select md5(url) url, raw_url
    from unnest(array['v1.com', 'v2.com']) as data(url)
) _ using (url)

